# Calling original method when overriding array push

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm attempting to override `push` on an array. I need to be able to call the original `push` method before overriding so I can push the element onto the array.

Below is my code. I've added `list.push` within the `value` method. I know this is wrong, but I added it to show what I am trying to do.

```
let list = [
  'One',
  'Two',
  'Three'
]

Object.defineProperty(list, 'push', {
  value: function(el) {
    list.push(el) // I know this is wrong. Example of what I am trying to do. 
  }
})
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to overwrite a native method, both on a prototype or on instantiated objects

Comment: Could you please explain why it's a bad idea and what's the alternative? Here's the completed code: http://codepen.io/JamesTheHacker/pen/dXvdBb

I decided to override `push` because after an element is pushed to an array I want `push` to call another method. I.e. fire an event when an item is pushed.

If you have a better, alternative, approach thats a "better" way to do this I would love to hear it. Thanks.

Comment: @LUH3417 feel free to answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38098876/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-override-native-methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invoke the original prototype implementation with your current object as context:

```
Array.prototype.push.call(this, el)
```