# Why is it a bad idea to override native methods?

Tags: javascript

I posted a question where I was overriding `push` using `Object.defineProperty`. The original question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096124/calling-original-method-when-overriding-array-push?noredirect=1#comment63627379_38096124). The code I was working on is on [my codepen](http://codepen.io/JamesTheHacker/pen/dXvdBb).

A user left a the following comment:

> It's a bad idea to overwrite a native method, both on a prototype or on instantiated objects

Why?

The reason why I decided to override `push` was because I needed to have `push` call another method after an element had been pushed. I am not changing the functionality of what push does except to have it fire an event on completion.

Is it bad to do what I did and if so what is the alternative?

Comment: Wow, my comment led to a follow-up question :D I guess you have your answer.

Comment: @LUH3417 I hate doing things that are considered incorrect :p You spurred me to find an alternative, better, solution.

Answer (score 6):

One problem that I can think of is that now you have a push method that is very specific to your problem, and what if you later need the normal push method. You don't really know if this will be the case or not, but it might cause you to have to refactor your code later, to allow for both the "normal push" and the "altered push".

Another problem that I can think of, is that if you do something like this and you are not the only one working on the code, someone else might not know that push is overridden and does not follow the standard behaviour anymore.

This could cause potential issues. You might not have changed it a lot, but in case the changes you made cause an error, you might leave someone else scratching his head wondering why a (in his opinion normal) push is causing odd behaviour.

Comment: What would be the alternative? I' guessing an an object that extends Array?

Comment: @BugHunterUK, an alternative is to create a regular function.

Comment: @hansmaad that is true, even for yourself that would be problematic!
And indeed BugHunterUK, as he suggested, just make a normal function for this ;-)

Comment: You can add custom functions to prototype. Something like this: `Array.prototype.pushAndCreateLI = function(){}`

Comment: @Rajesh even that is considered a bad practice. What if (in this case it's unlikely but still) W3C decides to create a function `pushAndcreateLI`.

Comment: @Dieterg Thats true. That is why I used such big name. Ideally if we are doing such thing, we should avoid using generic names. Instead use little bigger and self explanatory names that is specific to your requirement. If possible we can even add special mnemonic like `Array.prototype._appId_pushAndCreateLI = function(){}`